# Add personal locations to Google Placeautocomplete list

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2, placeautocompletefragment

Is there a way to pin an address to the top of a placeautocomplete search for an android app?

http://jsfiddle.net/v9rt3t2y/

```
This example is in JS/HTML, but I couldn't find anything for native android studio.
```

Comment: Have you tried https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway you can use customized [`AutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView) like in [this](http://www.zoftino.com/google-places-auto-complete-android) article. You should add your custom place name in `protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)` just after filling places list from `results.values;` from [`Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse>`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically).

So, for custom place name `"-> Custom place <-"` with `MainActivity.java` like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private SupportMapFragment mMapSupportedFragment;

    private AutoCompleteTextView mPlaceAutoCompleteTextView;
    private PlacesAdapter mPlacesAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlacesAdapter = new PlacesAdapter(this);
        mPlaceAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete);
        mPlaceAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
        mPlaceAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(mPlacesAdapter);

        mMapSupportedFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mMapSupportedFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    }

    class PlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        Context context;
        List<String> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
        GeoDataClient geoDataClient;
        PlacesAdapter.PlacesAutoCompleteFilter filter = new PlacesAdapter.PlacesAutoCompleteFilter();

        public PlacesAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                    new ArrayList<Place>());
            this.context = context;

            geoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(context, null);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return placesList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return placesList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return filter;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            if (view == null) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                                parent, false);
            }

            TextView textOne = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textOne.setText(placesList.get(position));

            return view;
        }

        class PlacesAutoCompleteFilter extends Filter {
            private Object lock = new Object();
            private Object lockTwo = new Object();
            private boolean placeResults = false;


            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                placeResults = false;
                final List<String> predictedPlacesList = new ArrayList<>();

                if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        results.values = new ArrayList<Place>();
                        results.count = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    final String searchStrLowerCase = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                    Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> task
                            = getAutoCompletePlaces(searchStrLowerCase);

                    task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Auto complete prediction successful");
                                AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse predictions = task.getResult();
                                for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : predictions) {
                                    predictedPlacesList.add((prediction.getFullText(null)).toString());
                                }
                                predictions.release();
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Auto complete prediction unsuccessful");
                            }

                            placeResults = true;
                            synchronized (lockTwo) {
                                lockTwo.notifyAll();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    while (!placeResults) {
                        synchronized (lockTwo) {
                            try {
                                lockTwo.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    results.values = predictedPlacesList;
                    results.count = predictedPlacesList.size();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Autocomplete predictions size after wait" + results.count);
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results.values != null) {
                    placesList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                } else {
                    placesList = null;
                }

                // add your custom place here:
                placesList.add(0, "-> Custom place <-");

                if (results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            private Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> getAutoCompletePlaces(String query) {
                AutocompleteFilter.Builder filterBuilder = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder();

                Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results =
                        geoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(query, null,
                                filterBuilder.build());
                return results;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and `activity_main.xml` (NB! according to [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#usage_limits):

> - If your app uses the autocomplete service programmatically, your UI
>     must either display a 'Powered by Google' attribution, or appear
>     within a Google-branded map.

) like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>.MainActivity">

    <fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                          android:layout_margin="16dp"
                          android:padding="8dp"
                          android:inputType="text"
                          android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                          android:textSize="16sp"
                          android:hint="Type place name here" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

when you enter letter "a" to text field you should get something like that:

[image: Custom Place Autocomplete Filter]

And don't forget to activate Places SDK on [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis).